# Gmail Contact api

Tags: api, gmail, contacts

For my application I need to import the Gmail Address book, which I am able to do by following "Gmail Contact API".

Recently Gmail added some of the new fields(i.e. Birthday,Website etc) which are not the part of xml. The gmail api docs mention that the new added field is part of XML namespace http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008, but I am unable to figure it out that how to fetch new fields using this name space which I am able to extract.

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/reference.html#gContactNamespace

Comment: can you be more specific about what the problem is and what tools you are using

Comment: The XML namespace http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008 contains many contacts-specific elements.

It is usually referred to using the alias gContact. 

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/reference.html#gContactNamespace

so how to get element from the above namespace.in gmail contact api ...the have not specified clearly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not certain what the problem you are having is. You linked to the page that contains all the information on the new API structure. Everything is the same as before. If you want to fetch these new fields, all you have to do is add the new fields to your calls. Below are all the names of the new fields:
[alt text http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/newFields.png](http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/newFields.png)

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade to the latest version of the client library: [Migrate to Google API 3.0](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/migration_guide.html#Migrating)

Currently only the Protocol and Java client library have been updated to use the new v3.0 api.

If you're using the Java client, you can use getWhen() on the Birthday: [JavaDoc Birthday](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/contacts/Birthday.html)

Answer (score 1):

When working on the Perl module [WWW::Contact::GoogleContactsAPI](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aContact%3a%3aGoogleContactsAPI), I wrote:

```
my $url = "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
    . "?max-results=9999&alt=json";
$url .= "&v=3.0"; # Gives more fields
```

That last line appends "&v=3.0" to the URL, which tells Google to return the extra fields.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this component : http://www.johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually answer the questions -- it's a link to an implementation of code that talks to an earlier version of the API.