# Programatically adding "Birthday" to Google Contacts using Google contact API?

Tags: c#, api, gmail, contacts

I am trying to add "Birthday" value to Google Contact using Google Contact API (C#).
Can anyone help me out here.

I am using Google Data API Setup(1.4.0.2).
I got one solution as specified on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158784/gmail-contact-api)

But to implement accepted solution i need to  upgrade to the latest version of the client library i.e API 3.0.

But for .Net i am not getting Version 3 API.
What should i do in such situation?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=5dfdb7ff0609cb80&hl=en

The .NET client library only uses Version 2... Birthday API functions are availble in Verison 3.  My suggestion is to recompile the .NET client library using Version 3 of the API and try to iron out a few things of the errors yourself.  It's a good exercise for fun and certainly not impossible.

Much better answer than just saying "It's impossible".

Comment: Actually, the current experimental source code is using Version 3 of the API.  It's not stable, but you can surely fix any issues and use that release

Comment: Not getting solution on Link specified in Solution :  
(http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/checkout) check the link

Comment: You can't get a solution, you would have to compile the latest version of the API yourself and do this from scratch.  You can always directly call the API but there's not a "solution" to this problem.  You would have to do alot of stuff manually.  That link sends you to the SVN checkout page where you can checkout a .NET library that is unstable that used the v3 of the Contacts API.  This will take a LOT of legwork, and there is NOT a simple code solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [API Documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) of Google Contact APIs for .NET.

There is an example on that Exact page on how you add contacts.

Comment: I know how to add contact.But i am not able to add Birthday entry