# How to grab email contacts?

Tags: php, gmail, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gmail Contact api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158784/gmail-contact-api)

How can i get **(grab) email contacts by supplying Username and Password**?
From Gmail, for example.

Please suggest or point me real working one.

Comment: Because this isn't suspicious at all.

Comment: I just love handing over my email credentials to every tom/dick/harry website that wants them so they can spam the heck out of my friends with useless blather about how wonderful their (non)service is...

Comment: Urgh. You're only redeeming hope is that you plea you work for an agency who's doing this on the demands of a client. Visit: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/, after you've visited the duplicate.

Comment: Wow.. you really were direct to the point! no no no..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the OpenInviter http://openinviter.com/ , I believe you can get the full contact list from most popular social/email services. This would get you going on how to get started, as its open source and you can go through the code to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, this is really useful and 100% what i need. Also it is great of being Opensource.